# Identification of nylon 3-pin connector

Tags: connector, identification

I'm hoping someone can help me identify this connector housing. It is 3-pin nylon and keyed by small squares in two corners. I've searched all through Mouser, Digikey, TE, etc and haven't found it.

[image: Notice the two corners have squares to key the mating connector]

Comment: Can you measure the spacing between the pins and report back to us?

Comment: It may be a week before I get back to the shop, but I believe it is .250" (6.35mm) pitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me a lot like a "Molex connector", used to supply power to hard drives in older computers. EXCEPT, those connectors were 4 pins, not 3.

Going to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector , it seems that these are now most often not Molex brand, but "AMP MATE-N-LOK" connectors (which is slightly further confused since AMP is now called TE Connectivity.)

Wikipedia calls the specific 4-pin connector I'm familiar with an "AMP MATE-N-LOK 1-480424-0 Power connector".

The closest match I was able to find for your 3-pin connector with square keys in two corners is this:

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/1-480303-0/A1429-ND/19287

It appears to be called an AMP 1-480303-0 connector. The pitch is 0.200", not 0.250". Hopefully it will match when you check yours! If not, I'd bet yours is some other AMP MATE-N-LOK connector I wasn't able to find; perhaps with that information you'll be able to locate it.

Comment: I'm betting that the connector you've found is indeed the proper one. I may just order a few and see if they happen to work when I get back to the project.

Comment: @chris I can't comment on another answer because I don't have enough rep here, but I see you identified the source of the connector as a Cirrus SR22 aircraft. You should have said in the original question! ;-) Take a look at the wiring manual, which is online:

The whole manual (find the section for the light in question, which will have a wiring diagram with a number): http://servicecenters.cirrusdesign.com/techpubs/pdf/WM/SR22/html/wmtoc.html

The section at the end enumerating all the connectors used: http://servicecenters.cirrusdesign.com/techpubs/pdf/WM/SR22/pdf/91-10-00.pdf

Comment: Also, please remember to mark the answer as accepted! :-)

Comment: Thanks so much. You were correct in your original identification of the connector and confirmed with the reference to the cirrus techpubs. Thanks so much.

Comment: Awesome, happy I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Could be a proprietary connector.
What is it used in?
More info would help.
The big brands like SONY have a such a buying power that they have connectors made specifically for them, so you will never see them on anyone else's product.

Comment: Used for interconnect of navigations lights on a Cirrus SR22 aircraft.